# Show only free shipping if subtotal is greater than 100 and not to show if less than 100

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have two shipping method enabled `Free Shipping` and `Flat Rate`

I would like to show `Free Shipping` is the only option if total order amount is greater than 100

And show `Flat Rate` as only option if total order amount is less than 100.

I created Shopping cart price rule in such a way that

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

Shipping Method  is  [freeshipping] Free 
Subtotal  greater than  100 
Shipping Method  is not  [flatrate] Fixed 
Subtotal  greater than  100
```

This way it is working fine if order amount is less than 100. It is not showing `Free Shipping` option. But when order is greater than 100 it shows both the options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly enough I've only gotten something like this to work by setting the free shipping method to no (disabled).

Then create a shopping cart price rule that grants free shipping when the subtotal is greater than 100.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to show both the options.

For the free shipping method you will need to set field Minimum Order Amount to 100 in admin.

```
Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Shipping Methods -> Free Shipping ->  Minimum Order Amount
```

For the flat rate you will need to rewrite the class

```
app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php
```

And function `collectRates` and you need to change in function as below.

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        $freeBoxes = 0;
        if ($request->getAllItems()) {
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {

                if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                    foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                        if ($child->getFreeShipping() && !$child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                            $freeBoxes += $item->getQty() * $child->getQty();
                        }
                    }
                } elseif ($item->getFreeShipping()) {
                    $freeBoxes += $item->getQty();
                }
            }
        }
        $this->setFreeBoxes($freeBoxes);

        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
        if ($this->getConfigData('type') == 'O') { // per order
            $shippingPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');
        } elseif ($this->getConfigData('type') == 'I') { // per item
            $shippingPrice = ($request->getPackageQty() * $this->getConfigData('price')) - ($this->getFreeBoxes() * $this->getConfigData('price'));
        } else {
            $shippingPrice = false;
        }

        $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($shippingPrice);

       if($shippingPrice > 100) {
         return false;
       }

        if ($shippingPrice !== false) {
            $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

            $method->setCarrier('flatrate');
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

            $method->setMethod('flatrate');
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

            if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true || $request->getPackageQty() == $this->getFreeBoxes()) {
                $shippingPrice = '0.00';
            }


            $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
            $method->setCost($shippingPrice);

            $result->append($method);
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Other method is simpler :-) +1

Answer (score 1):

You may do it easily by using Table Rate shipping method. There, you just have to create a rule for Price Less than 100 & More than 100. If you wish to give a unique label like "**Free Shipping**" or "**Flat Rate**", you may use WebShopApps MatrixRate which is a Free Module.

Here is the sample CSV :

```
Country,Region/State,Zip/Postal Code,Order Subtotal,Shipping Price
*,*,*,0,10
*,*,*,100,0
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable flat rate shipping and free shipping modify the collectRates function in flatrate.php

file path: app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }

    $freeBoxes = 0;
    if ($request->getAllItems()) {
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {

            if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }

            if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                    if ($child->getFreeShipping() && !$child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                        $freeBoxes += $item->getQty() * $child->getQty();
                    }
                }
            } elseif ($item->getFreeShipping()) {
                $freeBoxes += $item->getQty();
            }
        }
    }
    $this->setFreeBoxes($freeBoxes);

    $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
    if ($this->getConfigData('type') == 'O') { // per order
        $shippingPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');
    } elseif ($this->getConfigData('type') == 'I') { // per item
        $shippingPrice = ($request->getPackageQty() * $this->getConfigData('price')) - ($this->getFreeBoxes() * $this->getConfigData('price'));
    } else {
        $shippingPrice = false;
    }

   $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($shippingPrice);
   $session= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
   $getotal = Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
   $totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals(); //Total object
   $subtotal = $totals["subtotal"]->getValue();
   if($subtotal >100) {
     return false;
   }

    if ($shippingPrice !== false) {
        $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

        $method->setCarrier('flatrate');
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod('flatrate');
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true || $request->getPackageQty() == $this->getFreeBoxes()) {
            $shippingPrice = '0.00';
        }


        $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
        $method->setCost($shippingPrice);

        $result->append($method);
    }

    return $result;
}
```